# Is EE 3.4.5 buggy?

Tags: ee2, ee3, ee

I was banned as a member and paying EE licensee from replying to Ingmar Greil on a post I made on The EE forums here at the following link:

https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/249532/is-ee-3.4.5-buggy

I was hoping to be able to leave my comment but, since I was banned from replying hopefully this message will get to Ingmar Greil from here:

Here are the comments:

-

> Hello,
>
> After trying to post another reply on this thread I was greeted by the following EE' error Message:
>
> "Error Message
>
> Due to a heavy increase of spam within our community, the privilege of posting certain content is currently reserved for active community members and those who have purchase our software. If you feel you have received this in error, please contact sales@expressionengine.com with a support key of luktpi3v-g1sOk008-kOs848sc-Ooowg82s for more information"
>
> I am a member of the EE community and I have purchased countless EE licenses.
>   Anyway, here is my response to Ingmar Greil that I couldn't reply to in my original message:
>
> For future visitors encountering the same issues, please note that upgrading from 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.8 requires third-party repositories. These upgrades tend to break functionality of some control panel updates (like mine). Do your own research very carefully. EE is naturally motivated by their own needs as a profit-making company, and they will not absorb the costs of fixing our complex problems. So from their perspective, they save money by retiring older software, but we as customers may not be yet ready to jump. That's why server OS's like CentOS and Redhat are considered stable and used by companies that need long-term stability and support of their software. Likewise, those types of companies using EE need longer support and stability of tried and tested versions.
>
> My only request to EE would be to continue to support V2 for a longer run since it is very stable. I have implemented EE on many sites over the past several years because of the fantastic development that began their entire operation with the invention of CodeIgniter and the earlier versions of EE which were developed to a point of excellent stability. I hate to see such a fantastic product degrade to the chaotic state of Wordpress' control panel - with its pull of news feeds, constant pings out to the parent and plugin developers sites etc -  when EE began as a very unique product on the landscape of CMS's with its elegant and simple platform.

-

> Hello,
>
> Is EE 3.4.5 buggy? For example, I cannot create grid fields and have the fields permanently saved. Also, Do I really have to update php version to 5.3.10? My websites are running 5.3.3 on centos 6.8 fine. However, I’ve read on the other forums that updating to 5.3.10 can break some sites. If so, am I forced to revert to EE 2 which runs perfectly fine but will soon be phased out? Seems odd to do that when EE 2 works solidly.
>
> This is lost time and money for me, particularly since I purchased several EE 3 plugins that I may not be able to use. To top it all off, EE 3 puts a link on the control panel page for submitting bugs to EE… Should this be something my clients are subjected to do? They must become beta testers for EE but will not be compensated for it? EE is not a community working together on a FREE software project. That’s why I’m asking the question, is EE 3 buggy?
>
> eeadmin

-

> "Do I really have to update php version to 5.3.10?"
>
> Yes, EE needs at least PHP version 5.3.10. That said, this release is almost five (!) years old, so you really should be upgrading anyway.
>
> Ingmar Greil
>   29243 Posts

Comment: So you were running EE2 with current centOS and then you upgraded to EE3 where u were required to upgrade php version? What exactly is your question, grid field issue (EE3) or upgrade to php or EOL timeframe for EE2?

Comment: My question was - is EE3 buggy (and thus the "submit bug report" link placed in the admin control panel). Or is the bugginess due to the need for the upgraded PHP version? One of the biggest "bugs"  I discovered when I transferred my local install of EE 3.4.4 to the live server and tried to add a grid field and found it did not work. Another poster here on SE had the same issue but got no answers. So after spending a lot of time with EE3 and buying several plugins, I returned to EE2 and have no issues now, but this version will no longer be supported next year.

Comment: Here is yet another comment on the EE forums regarding my question that I'm not able to answer since I've been blocked after posting my question:
___
https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/249532/is-ee-3.4.5-buggy

"Every software ever written has bugs, and every company from Apple to EllisLab relies on users of their software to report bugs. If you want a page that's driven by software that's bug free, you'll probably have to stick to paper and ink ;) "
posted by Pedro Guimaraes

Comment: FYI, as I said, EE2 works great on my old version of PHP. I'm just trying to find out if it's actually my php that is the bug or if it's worth it to upgrade my entire server that works fine (just so that I can bug test version EE3.4.5?). And I don't feel that my clients should have to see a link to report bugs as this is not their job. Pedro says that all software has bugs... in that case hang on to EE2 because it seems to be fairly bug-free at this point, and I don't think it should be retired when EE3 is not yet de-bugged properly

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing any major issues with EE v3 running on php version 5.6.2. I'm only running a few modules and I'm doing it all locally (Mamp).

In your scenario, I'd pull down the db/templates and set up a test environment (wamp/Mamp etc) and do tests for your circumstances.

Bug report links are a norm these days and if you feel so strongly about it, lodge a feature request with EllisLabs to have it hidden by member group.

Is it (EE3) buggy? - my handful of tests suggest that it's quite stable but as with all software, it must be tested to gauge if it suits your needs and environment.